# Derivative of incomplete Gamma function : $\Gamma(c,t/a)=\int_{0}^{t/a}x^{c-1}e^{-x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

How we can calculate derivative of incomplete Gamma. Can anyone give me these derivative.
$\frac{\partial\Gamma(c,t/a)}{\partial a}$
and
$\frac{\partial\Gamma(c,t/a)}{\partial c}$
where

$\Gamma(c,t/a)=\int_{0}^{t/a}x^{c-1}e^{-x}dx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. By the chain rule, one has
$$
\frac{\partial\Gamma(c,t/a)}{\partial a}=\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\int_{0}^{t/a}x^{c-1}e^{-x}dx=-\frac t{a^2}\times(t/a)^{c-1}e^{-t/a}
$$ and differentiating under the intgral sign one has
$$
\frac{\partial\Gamma(c,t/a)}{\partial c}=\frac{\partial}{\partial c}\int_{0}^{t/a}x^{c-1}e^{-x}dx=\int_{0}^{t/a}(\ln x)\cdot x^{c-1}e^{-x}dx.
$$